@PermissionsAllowed Quarkus annotation and Keycloak configuration. Behaviour is not what I expect
My controller:
    @PermissionsAllowed("objects:view")
    @GET
    @Path("/perm")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String permission() {
        return "Hello permission test allowed";
    }

If I configure scope "objects:view" and add to my client in Keycloak I will reach this endpoint.
Is it expected behavior?
But I'm expecting to reach my endpoint configuring resource "objects" with scope "view", resource-based permission, and policy.
I consider "objects" as resource name and "view" as scope.
So, How do you use permissions in Quarkus?
